# Uploading binary file with retrofit2 most of the times fail because of ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: java, android, upload, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using retrofit2 for uploading binary image file:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
    RequestBody requestBody = new ProgressRequestBody(
            MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),
            file,
            this);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.uploadFile(requestBody);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                               Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toasti.showS("fail");
                return;
            }

            Log.v("Upload", "success");
            UploadFileOutput uploadFileOutput = new UploadFileOutput();
            try {
                uploadFileOutput =
                        new Gson().fromJson(response.body().string(), UploadFileOutput.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


  ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(uploadFileOutput.imageSrc, giftImageview);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
            Toasti.showS("fail");
        }
    });
```

But most of the times(sometimes it works fine!) it fails because of this error:

> sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

I read lots of post and tutorials:

[java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871636/java-net-socketexception-sendto-failed-econnreset-connection-reset-by-peer)

[Getting “SocketException : Connection reset by peer” in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207394/getting-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer-in-android)

[retrofit.RetrofitError: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1027#issuecomment-310966989)

But none of them helped me.

I test api method with postman, It always works without any error!

Comment: Mr down voter please say something! you can use comment first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of testing and searching I found that I should increase timeout of okhttp client by `readTimeout` and `readTimeout`:

```
longTimeOutHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    longTimeoutRetrofitBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient);
    longTimeOutRetrofit = longTimeoutRetrofitBuilder.baseUrl(URIs.BASE_URL + 
    URIs.API_VERSION).build();

    longTimeoutService = longTimeOutRetrofit.create(RestAPI.class);
```

This error occurs because of big file size and low internet speed, so the connection time outs.

Comment: I tried this with no luck in my case, it behaves exactly the same and throws the same error, sometimes working correctly, sometimes throwing the error.